# What did I do wrong with my Wordpress or DNS settings? Login loop

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wordpress, dns

We built a website for a client using Wordpress. We used a testing server which always works well. Wordpress was hosted as a subdomain, i.e. http://wordpress.ourcompany.com. I have direct and full access to the server. In the etc/apache2/sites-available directory the file describing the site in question uses the final name http://clientsite.com as ServerName, our temporary subdomain (under which we have been building) is a ServerAlias.

When we were almost ready, we of course asked the client (who already had a website) for their domain login. We changed the DNS like always. It resolved, the site worked well. Although Wordpress kept redirecting (of course) to the subdomain-variant, we could enter the site with the full domain.

Now comes the culprit. I changed the Wordpress settings (siteurl and home) to match the new site. The front-end works brilliantly. However, the back-end is unreachable as long as the settings are in this way. The login page shows up, but just redirects back to itself. If I simply change the Wordpress settings (in the options table) I can log back in, but we want to rid the subdomain necessity (of course).

Things I've already tried (I'm not one to easily ask of your time):

- Clear .htaccess
- Clear my cache & cookies
- Different computer, different browser etc.
- Change only the home and not the blogurl value. Sadly, this corrupts some plug-ins
- Remove all plugins
- Comment some lines as instructed in the wp-login file
- Naturally, everything I could find on codex.wordpress
- Set the admin cookie path

So, brilliant collective mind that is Stack Overflow, what did I do wrong? DNS? Wordpress settings? Thank you in advance.

Comment: so its fair to assume you have tried everything in http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried all the relevant codex articles. Thanks.

Comment: did you found the answer? I have that problem aswell!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the settings on the live server and change the URL's to the current site. You'll have to do this by accessing the database directly. It's the **wp-options table**, and there are 2 entries where the url's are the value. Update those. That should fix the looping.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I already tried this (several times), but no avail. Perhaps I wasn't too clear about that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer today : the user in the database didn't had the right permissions. You can look up in the error log if there are lines that indicates this.

I also had tried before : removing all content from htacess, reinstalling wordpress etc.